# (...) and neither are/is they?

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

Although it is widely disseminated that "neither", as well as "either" is [s](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2)[i](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/neither-singular-or-plural/#:%7E:text=Most%20grammatical%20authorities%20and%20style,instead%20of%20%E2%80%9Cneither%20are.%E2%80%9D)ngular, I bring you the following sentence:

> I'**m** not a good person, and neither **is** they.

I don't know why, but **"is"** sounds me a bit odd.

Should I continue with **"is"** or use **"are"**?

Thank you all. 0/

*ps: I'm a good person, btw ahaha.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"They" is the **subject**, and not "neither". The pronoun is *plural* Had you written it in the opposite order, it would have been, "They **are** not good persons, and neither **am** I."

Some examples for clarification:

- Neither Tom nor Eve **is** in class. [both sing.]
- Neither cloves nor salt is in the recipe. [noun closest to verb is sing., and to me, the sing. verb form is needed]
- Neither salt nor cloves are in the recipe. [noun closest to verb is pl., and to me, the pl. verb form is needed]

Comment: Thank you, Dr.Moishe. It's clearer now. Take care.